# Which has more Shannon entropy (H): a discrete Power-law distribution, or a discrete normal Gaussian distribution, and how to calculate? TY

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Which has more Shannon entropy (H): a discrete Power-law distribution, or a discrete normal Gaussian distribution, and how to calculate? TY
I've tried summing the individual probabilities $P(x_1), P(x_2), P(x_3)\ldots$then multiplying the sum by $\log_2$ of the sum.

However, the power-law shape doesn't seem to be relevant. Please, help me understand how to calculate these two distinct (discrete) distributions.

Thank you.

Comment: The Shannon entropy is defined as $$\sum_i P(x_i) \log P(x_i),$$ which is not the same as $$\left(\sum_i P(x_i)\right) \left(\sum_j \log (P(x_j))\right),$$ nor is it $$\log\left(\sum_i P(x_i)\right) \times \sum_i P(x_i).$$ It sounds like you did one of the latter two?

Comment: Correction: it should be $$-\sum_i P(x_i) \log P(x_i)$$